# How expensive is an array allocation and initialization?

Tags: c#

TL;D: How expensive is allocation and initialization of an array of  of relatively large size K, compared to going through such an array, multiplying each float by a fixed float, and writing the result in a different array of size K? E.g. is there a big difference between doing both (allocate, initialize, multiply), or just doing the latter (multiply elements of existing array)?

---

I'll be recursively traversing through an unknown binary tree of height at most ~50, that has some attributes already set, and I'll be filling out some other attributes. Each node contains an array/list containing around 10k floats, I'll do some operation on all the floats of this array in the node - say multiply them by a float, and then the resulting 10k array will go down to the children.

Now to me the neatest way to implement this would be to actually just declare a tree node class and recursively create the children, etc. Thing is, the values in the node can only really effect the children nodes - so I don't actually need to create an array in each node. Since I have a bound of ~50 on the height of the tree, I could just use 50 arrays, one for each level of the tree. This seems a bit ugly to me though. Also, I'll still have to do the actual operation of a  multiplication, writing down the values, etc - so assuming complexity of initialization and allocation of a new array is linear in the size of the array (and I don't really know if that's true), then I'll still be doing 10k * number of nodes-many operations of multiplication, as opposed to 10k*number of nodes * (multiplication + initialization).

If it is a noticeable difference (which to me, something like say 0.1% difference is not), what would be the right way to use arrays that would keep track of the floats in the current node? Using static arrays would seem like the simplest solutions, but I'm sure that might be considered bad practice. I can't really think of another simple solution.

I was sort of expecting to just make a tree node class, and give it a traversal/"go down" method, keeping all the stuff in one class. But I guess I could make a different class with a function that would recursively traverse the tree, that might be cleaner anyway, as that way the new class could correspond to an actual "tree" object. Then I could just give tree object a field that would contain the arrays for each level.

Alternatively, I could still use just a node class with a traversal method, and just keep passing down a reference to an object with all of the 50 arrays.

Comment: Mitigating performance issues before you have measured an actual performance issue is always perhaps an undesirable step.  Doing so before you have written any code even more so

Comment: So if I've read the problem right, you don't really need to initialize the array.  You allocated and then run down one array, multiply and put the answer in the (perhaps uninitialized) second array.  The allocation shouldn't be that bad in that case.  However, given a binary tree of depth 50, you are talking like 1000 trillion nodes to process.  I think no matter what scheme you use, garbage collection is likely to be an issue.  Because of that, while I agree with you that 50 static arrays smells bad, it might be important because it will limit your garbage collection issues.

Comment: As a second thought, if you have 1000 trillion nodes with 10K float each you are talking about more data than will fit in any memory I am aware of.  So I assume your data is saving in some SQL database or something someplace.  In which case you'll be dead at the disk . . . array initialization isn't worth worrying about.  Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: @FrankMerrow Nope, I don't need to initialize the array, that's true. But I don't really know how to allocate a new array field when constructing a new object, without actually initializing it to zeros. But yes, that's actually an important point, thanks for mentioning, I do just need allocation an nothing else. The depth is 50, but the amount of nodes will be realistic, so that's not an issue. But it could happen that there is perhaps one very long branch of 50 nodes.

Comment: @MickyD It might take me a significant amount of time to do either of the options, and I'd like to plan around these options, as opposed to trying all of them out. Technically, I'm not sure I have a "performance issue", that's true, but my goal is not some sort of fixed time - I'm doing this for a game, and the less time all this takes (within reason) the better. This might be semantics however - but again, I'm inexperienced, and I'm not sure how I should go about this.

Comment: @MickyD So I'm slightly unsure about what you would propose in my situation - do you suggest I just try the simpler way and see if it's good enough? How do I figure out what's good enough though, when I feel like it could always be better, as long as it's say 1% difference or so. I guess I might be overly analyzing the situation, and should actually code more and profile the results, is that what you suggest?

Comment: Start with easiest solution that is straightforward to understand, debug and maintain. Then profile. If it's too slow or uses too much memory, change according to the results of the profiling. Then profile again and compare.

Comment: I'm saying that like anything in programming when unsure, start-off with a _prototype_.   _research; experiment; debug; analyse; adjust; ship!_.  _[Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)_